# Ошибка при попытке входа в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, denwer

Открываю http://localhost/Tools/phpMyAdmin/

Вводил пароль и логин.  И там ошибка:

```
#2002 Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL
```

Запускаю через командную строку

```
ERROR 2003 <HY000>: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' <10061>
```

Останавливаю работу Денвера:

Останавливаем работу MySQL...
MySQL не запущен.
В чем проблема?

ЗЫ: Пробовал переустановить Денвер, но не помогло

Comment: Ну сперва смотрим логи mysql, проверьте служба mysql вообще  запускается.

Comment: Так, может, проблема именно в том, что "MySQL не запущен"? Руками запускать не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас mysql слушает не localhost а 127.0.0.1.

**/etc/my.cnf**

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

тогда вам нужно немного подредактировать конфиг phpmyadmin

**/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
```